# I need to open SharePoint link in client application in edit mode. Can you please help?

Tags: javascript

I need to open SharePoint link in client application in edit mode. Below given is the code I am using. It is not working. I don't know where am doing mistakes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sp.js/2014.01/sp.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/15/SP.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        function openSharePointLink() {
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web();
            var url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/sites/training/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B308F2322-BA11-4D1B-A3FD-FB090729F027%7D&file=Lab%20Excercises.docx&action=default&mobileredirect=true"; // Replace with your SharePoint link URL

            web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(url)
                .getListItemAllFields()
                .getShareObject()
                .launchSharingDialog();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="openSharePointLink()">Open SharePoint Link</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

To open a document in the client desktop app, you can simply open a link that will look like this:

```
ms-word:ofe|u|https://your-sharepoint-site-url/path/to/your-document.docx
```

We use "**ms-word:ofe|u|**" to indicate which application will be opened.

In your example, you can simplify your code with just the below:

```
<a href="ms-word:ofe|u|https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/training/Documents/Lab%20Excercises.docx">Open Document</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. But Not working...

Comment: I does work… But obviously you need Microsoft Word installed on the computer :-) Please, note that I give the direct link to the .docx file, and I'm not passing the Doc.aspx page!